# Get access to map in a vector: map<string, vector<map<string, vector<int> > > >

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, mapreduce

I have following own created datatype:

```
typedef map<string, vector<map<string, vector<int> > > > Entry;
```

Which should represent following datastructure:

```
Filename | vector<map<Word, vector<LineNumber> > >
```

wich means, each FileName contains many words and each word contains linNumbers. It represent be an Index of words over many files.

For this suppose I wrote a functor, which should add the fileName, word and lnr to my datastructure:

```
FileWordLineAdder(string fileName, Entry wordLnr, int lnr) : fileName(fileName), entries(wordLnr), lnr(lnr) {
}

void operator()(string word) {
    word = normalize(word);
    if (word.size() == 0)
        return;

    vector<map<string, vector<int> > >& wordLnr = entries[fileName];

/* PROBLEM START */

    //vector<int>& lnrs = wordLnr[word];
    //lnrs.push_back(lnr);

/* PROBLEM END*/
} // operator()
```

Right now I am able to insert the fileName to my datastructure (see line above PROBLEM section), but I am not able to get access to my map in the vector.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a `map` of `map`? I.e. `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>>`.

Comment: Or even a `map` of `multimap`s? I.e. `map<string, multimap<string, int> >`.

Comment: But why multimap? It is an index of word's line numbers over files. There most probably is no point in keeping **copies of words** in the index! On the other hand, if you would like to split the index over exact individual copy of a word, then it would exist on a exact single line (individual!), and then a map-of-map-of-tuple(string,int) would form the index.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: But in your example with the map of a map it is not possible that I have following structure:

File1 | <word1 <1, 2, 3, 4>, word2 <9, 12>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution looks as follows:

```
typedef map<string/*word*/, vector<unsigned long> /*lineNumber*/> IndexInnerMap;
typedef map<string/*filename*/, IndexInnerMap> Index;

    // Get innerMap of specific fileName
    IndexInnerMap& wordLnr = index[fileName];
    // Get vector<lineNumber> of specific word
    vector<unsigned long>& lnrs = wordLnr[word];
    // Add line number to vector
    if (lnrs.empty() || lnrs.back() != lnr) {
        lnrs.push_back(lnr);
    } // if
```

Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think you have overdesigned your data structure. For an index of "file -> word -> linenumbers" a simple:

```
Filename | map<Word, vector<LineNumber> >
```

i.e.

```
map<string/*filename*/, map<string/*word*/, vector<unsigned long/*lineNumber*/ > > >
```

would probably be just sufficient. Please note that this data structure is already **the whole index**. It is not 'an Entry', so your typedef might be misnamed.

(Note that I removed one level of "vector" that was over the map - I think it was the actual source of your problem. With `vector<map<...>>` you'd have many word-maps for a filename, and you'd probably not know which one map to choose.)

Comment: But I cannot use an unsigned long, because a word can appear in more than one line number, thats the reason why i used a vector<LineNumber>

But I would like to have many word-maps for a filename. Each filename should contain many words and each word contains many line numbers

Comment: Sorry, I misedited my post. The Filename|map<word,vector<linenumber>> that I wrote above is 100% CORRECT, while the code example is not. I will fix that ASAP

Comment: Ok, fixed! Please check the typename now.

Comment: Okay now I got it: I will use following datastructure: `map<string/*filename*/, map<string/*word*/, vector<unsigned long/*lineNumber*/ > > >` I didn't got it that I do not need the vector, I just ned a map of map.